# C# ForecastIOPortable lib in WPF application with Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I'm trying to get weather information using ForecastIOPortable library.
I have a method that works without problems in Console application, same in WPF application.

```
ForecastApi api = new ForecastApi("XXXX");
var forecast = api.GetWeatherDataAsync(XXXX, XXXX);
var results = forecast.Result;
int tempC = (int)(5.0 / 9.0 * (results.Currently.Temperature - 32));
```

Problem shows when I try to call that method with tick of timer, program freezes and VS doesn't show information about exception.
When I checked breakpoints, I get information that results doesn't change and all time has value=null.
What is the reason of problem and how to deal with it?

Comment: As you are calling an Async method in a console app you would need to check what the type of the forecast variable is defined as.  If you can post what the type is it might help.  I am guessing it will be a Task<Forecast>.

Generally I have fallen into the habit of using var for instantiations of new objects and use the actual type I am calling a Method or Property.  This means you can clearly see what the assignment is.

Comment: yes, the type of variable forecast is: 
          Task<ForecastIOPortable.Models.Forecast>

Answer (score 1):

You are using an async process so you will you will be getting the a Task rather than the result.

In a console app you generally have to .Wait() for the task to resolve before the result will be populated.  You would be better to test using a WPF application where you can await the GetWeatherDataAsync method.

Probably the best way to handle it is to wrap the timer in a class and pass in the various bits.

You can try this

```
public class ForecastApiAsyncTimer : IDisposable
{
    private ForecastApi _api;
    private Timer _timer;

    public ForecastApiAsyncTimer(Timer timer, ForecastApi forecastApi)
    {
        if (timer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("timer");

        if (forecastApi == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("forecastApi");

        _api = forecastApi;
        _timer = timer;
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
    }

    public ForecastApiAsyncTimer(double interval, ForecastApi forecastApi)
    {
        if (forecastApi == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("forecastApi");

        _api = forecastApi;
        _timer = new Timer(interval);
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    protected async virtual Task<int> TimerElapsedTask()
    {
        var forecast = await _api.GetWeatherDataAsync(40.7505045d, -73.9934387d);
        int tempC = (int)(5.0 / 9.0 * (forecast.Currently.Temperature - 32));
        return tempC;
    }

    async void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        int result = await TimerElapsedTask();
        // do something with result.
    }

    ~ForecastApiAsyncTimer()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing || _timer == null)
            return;

        _timer.Dispose();
        _timer = null;
    }
}
```

Example usage 1.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string apiKey = "yourApiKey";
    ForecastApi api = new ForecastApi(apiKey);

    using (var forecastTimer = new ForecastApiAsyncTimer(5000, api))
    {
        forecastTimer.Start();
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Example usage 2:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string apiKey = "yourApiKey";
    ForecastApi api = new ForecastApi(apiKey);
    Timer timer = new Timer(5000);

    var forecastTimer = new ForecastApiAsyncTimer(timer, api);
    forecastTimer.Start();
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: You can create new classes that inherit that one and override the TimerElapsedTask or you can modify the constructor to take the lat and long.

Comment: I 'm not sure, i understand that good, it's first time I've met Tasks. As I see that, your class creates timer that contains Forecast Api and can use that - that's cool. But problem looks that I have Timer, where event call methods from another component, so I don't need to have new timer, but i need to can call method from Forecast api, from another component than Timer is, that return Int value.

Comment: Tasks are wrappers typically used in asynchronous operations. I would advise reading http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: I have updated the class to allow you to pass in your own instance of a timer.